# Outlier Detection on skewed Distributions

Tags: distributions, outliers, skewness, exponential-distribution, interquartile

Under a classical definition of an outlier as a data point outide the 1.5* IQR from the upper or lower quartile, there is an assumption of a non-skewed distribution. For skewed distributions (Exponential, Poisson, Geometric, etc) is the best way to detect an outlier by analyzing a transform of the original function?

For example, distributions loosely governed by an exponential distribution, could be transformed with a log function - at which point is it acceptable to look for outliers based on the same IQR definition?

Comment: There are many questions on this site on assessing outliers. One thing you'd need to add here to get a reasonable answer is what you're really trying to do or find out. But for starters, the `1.5*IQR` definition of an outlier is not universally accepted. Try to unload your question and expand on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The statement that a value in excess of 1.5 IQR is an outlier is simply nonsense. Data in excess of 1.5 IQR would be entirely consistent with an infinite number of distributions, and as the sample size becomes large, one could have almost perfect confidence that such data were NOT outliers.

Answer (score 27):

> Under a classical definition of an outlier as a data point outide the 1.5* IQR from the upper or lower quartile,

This is the rule for identifying points outside the ends of the whiskers in a boxplot. Tukey himself would no doubt object to calling them outliers on this basis (he didn't necessarily regard points outside those limits as outliers). These would rather be points which - if your data was expected to be from a distribution somewhat similar to a normal distribution - one might subject to further investigation (such as checking you didn't transpose two digits, for example) -- at most these could be *potential* outliers. As Nick Cox points out in comments [under this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125521/why-does-tableaus-box-whisker-plot-show-outliers-automatically-and-how-can-i-ge/125522#125522), a tail of many such points would be taken more as a indicator that a re-expression might be suitable than an indication of the need to regard the points as outliers.

> there is an assumption of a non-skewed distribution.

I assumed by 'non-skewed' you mean symmetric. The two are not synonyms, but if you really mean non-skewed, we'd have to discuss with care what measure of skewness you're using, and we'd get tied up with issues of asymmetric cases with zero skewness. At least the symmetric case is not reliant on a particular choice of measurement and simpler to discuss. Then the assumption is more than just that it's symmetric. A heavy-tailed but symmetric distribution might have *many* points outside the bounds on that rule.

> For skewed distributions (Exponential, Poisson, Geometric, etc) is the best way to detect an outlier by analyzing a transform of the original function?

That depends on what constitutes an outlier for your purposes. There's no single definition that's suitable for each purpose - indeed, generally you're probably better off doing other things that (say) picking outliers and omitting them.

For the exponential or geometric, you might do a similar calculation to that for a boxplot, but which would identify a similar fraction in the right tail only (you won't have low-end points identified in an exponential or geometric)$^{\dagger}$ ... or you might do something else.

$\dagger$ In large samples from a normal distribution, the boxplot marks about 0.35% of points at each end, or about 0.7% in total. For an exponential you might mark some multiple of the median, for example. If you wanted to tag roughly 0.7% of points in total for an actual exponential, that would suggest marking points beyond about 7.1 times the median.

Marking points above 7.1 times the median for n=1000 will typically hit between 0.4% to 1.1% of values:

```
ae <- rexp(1000)
table( ae > 7.1*median(ae) )

FALSE  TRUE 
  993     7
```

> For example, distributions loosely governed by an exponential distribution, could be transformed with a log function - at which point is it acceptable to look for outliers based on the same IQR definition?

That totally depends on what you mean by "acceptable". Note, however that -

i) the resulting distribution (from taking logs of an exponential variable) isn't actually symmetric, but distinctly left-skew.

[image]

As a result, you'll usually only mark points in the *left end* (i.e. close to zero, where you expect exponential values to be anyway) rather than in the right (where the "outliers" might be), unless they're *really* extreme.

ii) suitability of such  a rule is going to be heavily dependent on what you're doing.

If you're concerned about the odd strange value affecting your inference, in general, you're probably better off using robust procedures than formally identifying outliers.

If you really do want to use a normal-based rule for transformed exponential or Poisson data, I'd at least suggest applying it to the square root$^{\ddagger}$ for a Poisson (as long as the mean isn't too small, it should be roughly normalish) and to cube root or even fourth root for the exponential (and perhaps, by extension, the geometric).

$\ddagger$ or perhaps $\sqrt{X+\frac{3}{8}}$, as in the [Anscombe transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform#Definition)

[image]

For an exponential, in large samples the cube-root approach will tend to mark points only in the upper tail (at roughly the same rate it marks them in the upper tail for a normal) and the fourth-root approach marks points in both tails (slightly more in the lower tail, in total at something near 40% of the rate it does so for a normal). Of the possibilities, the cube root makes more sense to me than the other two, but I wouldn't necessarily advise using this as some hard and fast rule.

As noted in some of my answers to other questions, a Weibull distribution is close to symmetric for shape parameter in a broad interval near 3.6 (exactly where it's closest depends on how you measure it), and fairly close to a normal. This suggests that rather than the cube root or fourth root with exponential variavles, something in the vicinity the 3.6-th root should very near symmetric, but cube roots and fourth roots are still quite reasonable.

Comment: "A heavy-tailed but symmetric distribution might have many points outside the bounds on that rule.". There are always exactly 50% of all points within the IQR, aren't they?

Comment: @muraveill Indeed -- but there's not always 0.7% of points outside $(Q_1-1.5\times \text{IQR},Q_3+1.5\times \text{IQR})$ which is the boxplot rule that's under discussion.

Comment: @Glen_b The upper rejection threshold for the exponential in your answer assumes that the shift parameter (or theta) is known. I think this should be mentioned.

Comment: @user603 The term "[exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)" (also see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialDistribution.html)) without any modifying adjective (like "shifted" or "two-parameter") most conventionally refers to the one-parameter version. Some people do call the shifted version "the exponential distribution", but that's relatively rare; only slightly more common than calling the shifted lognormal distribution "the lognormal distribution".

Comment: @user603 One the other hand, it's not hard to adapt the large-sample rule I gave to a two-parameter exponential case (subtract the minimum observation from every observation, omit the zero, apply the rule, add back the zero, add the minimum back), but then I would also actually be worried about different things (the transformation approach wouldn't work as is, and I would be much more worried about outliers at the left end). But then ought I talk about generalizations of the Poisson case as well (shifted, zero truncated,...)?

Comment: @Glen_b: Even setting aside the other issues you mention, it seems to me that the approach you propose (subtract the minimum observation from every observation, ..., add the minimum back) would not work in general. For example, in the second example in my answer, it would return an estimate of $\hat{\sigma}\approx11$ (using the 7.1 cut-off you propose). I agree with you that the 'exponential' most often refers to the one parameter version and that assuming $\theta$ known makes the problem considerably simpler.

Comment: @User603 Now I'm not sure if we're even talking about the same thing. The multiplying by 7.1 isn't to produce an estimate of the scale parameter, but to produce an extreme-tail cut-off to "mark as an outlier", as in the original question, but in a way that would identify a similar proportion as outliers as you'd get with using the boxplot rule on normal data. In your second example, the rule correctly identifies all 20 observations you multiplied by 100. It does not attempt to end up with a robust estimate of scale.

Comment: @user603 Oh, sorry, a simple miscommunication - in that case yes, I don't think we have any substantive disagreement -- where there's any possibility of large outliers to the left, the approach I mentioned *makes no sense at all*. I simply wasn't attempting to deal with any potential that situation (but in my defence, it didn't look to me like the OP considered it as a possibility - I doubt taking logs would have come to mind if it were).

Answer (score 16):

I will answer your questions in the opposite order in which you asked them, so that the exposition proceeds from the specific to the general.

First, let us consider a situation where you can assume that except for a minority of outliers, the bulk of your data can be well described by 
a known distribution (in your case the exponential).

If $x$ has pdf:

$$p_X(x)=\sigma^{-1}\mbox{exp}\left(\frac{-(x-\theta)}{\sigma}\right),\;x>0;\sigma>0$$

then $x$ is said to follow an exponential distribution (the special case where we set $\theta=0$ is called the one-parameter or standard exponential distribution).

The usual MLE estimator of the parameters are [0,p 506]:

$$\hat{\theta}=\min_i x_i$$

and

$$\hat{\sigma}=\mbox{ave}_ix_i-\min_i x_i$$

Here is an example in `R`:

```
n<-100
theta<-1
sigma<-2
set.seed(123) #for reproducibility
x<-rexp(n,rate=1/sigma)+theta
mean(x)-min(x)
```

the MLE of $\sigma$ is $\approx2.08$.

Unfortunately, the MLE estimates are very sensitive to the presence of outliers. For example, if I corrupt the sample by replacing 20% of the $x_i$'s by $-x_i$:

```
m<-floor(0.2*n)
y<-x
y[1:m]<--y[1:m]
mean(y)-min(y)
```

the MLE  of $\sigma$ based on the corrupted sample is now 
$\approx11.12$(!).
As a second example, if I corrupt the sample by replacing 20% of the $x_i$'s by $100x_i$ (say if the decimal place was accidentally misplaced):

```
m<-floor(0.2*n)
z<-x
z[1:m]<-100*z[1:m]
mean(z)-min(z)
```

the MLE  of $\sigma$ based on this second corrupted sample is now 
$\approx54$(!).

An alternative to the raw MLE is to (a) find the outliers using a *robust  outlier identification rule*, (b) set them aside as spurious data and (c) compute the MLE  on the non spurious part of the sample.

The most well known of these robust outlier identification rule is the med/mad rule proposed by Hampel[3] who attributed it to Gauss (I illustrated this rule [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/121075/603)). In the med/mad rule, the rejection threshold are based on the assumption that the genuine observations in your sample are well approximated by a normal distribution.

Of course,  if you have extra information (such as knowing that the distribution of the genuine observations is well approximated by a poisson distribution as in [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56404/603))
 there is nothing to prevent you from transforming your data and using the  baseline outlier rejection rule (the med/mad) but this strikes me as a bit  awkward to transform the data to preserve what is after all an ad-hoc rule.

It seems much more logical to me to preserve the data but adapt the rejection 
rules. Then, you would still use the 3 step procedure I described in the first link above, but with rejection threshold adapted to the distribution you suspect the good part of the data has. Below, I give the rejection rule in situations where the genuine observations are well fitted by an exponential distribution. In this case, you can construct good rejection thresholds using  the following rule:

1) estimate $\theta$ using [1]:

$$\hat{\theta}'=\mbox{med}_ix_i-3.476\mbox{Qn}(x)\ln2$$

The Qn is a robust estimate of scatter that is not geared towards symmetric data. It is widely implemented, for example in the R package [robustbase](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/index.html). For exponential distributed data, the Qn is multiplied by consistency factor of $\approx3.476$, see [1] for more details.

2) reject as spurious all observations outside of [2,p 188]

$$[\hat{\theta}',9(1+2/n)\mbox{med}_ix_i+\hat{\theta}']$$

(the factor 9 in the rule above is obtained as the 7.1 in Glen_b's answer above, but using a higher cut-off. The factor (1+2/n) is small sample correction factor that was derived by simulations in [2]. For large enough sample sizes, it is essentially equal to 1).

3) use the MLE  on the non spurious data to estimate $\sigma$:

$$\hat{\sigma}'=\mbox{ave}_{i\in H}x_i-\mbox{min}_{i\in H}x_i$$

where $H=\{i:\hat{\theta}'\leq x_i \leq 9(1+2/n)\mbox{med}_ix_i+\hat{\theta}'\}$.

using this rule on the previous examples, you would get:

```
library(robustbase)
theta<-median(x)-Qn(x,constant=3.476)*log(2)
clean<-which(x>=theta & x<=9*(1+2/n)*median(x)+theta)
mean(x[clean])-min(x[clean])
```

the robust estimate of $\sigma$ is now 
$\approx2.05$ (very close to the MLE value when the data is clean).
On the second example:

```
theta<-median(y)-Qn(y,constant=3.476)*log(2)
clean<-which(y>=theta & y<=9*(1+2/n)*median(y)+theta)
mean(y[clean])-min(y[clean])
```

The robust estimate of $\sigma$  is now 
$\approx2.2$ (very close to the value we would have gotten without the outliers).

On the third example:

```
theta<-median(z)-Qn(z,constant=3.476)*log(2)
clean<-which(z>=theta & z<=9*(1+2/n)*median(z)+theta)
mean(z[clean])-min(z[clean])
```

The robust estimate of $\sigma$  is now 
$\approx2.2$ (very close to the value we would have gotten without the outliers).

A side benefit of this approach is that it yields a subset of indexes of 
 suspect observations which should be set aside from the rest of the data, perhaps to be studied as object of interest in their own right (the members 
 of $\{i:i\notin H\}$).

Now, for the general case where you do not have a good candidate distribution 
to fit the bulk of your observations beyond knowing that a symmetric distribution won't do, you can use the adjusted boxplot[4]. This is a generalization of the boxplot that takes into account a (non parametric and outlier robust) measure of skewness of your data (so that when the bulk of the data is symmetric is collapses down to the usual boxplot). You can also check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13429/603) answer for an illustration.

- [0]  Johnson N. L.,  Kotz S.,  Balakrishnan N. (1994). Continuous Univariate Distributions, Volume 1, 2nd Edition.
- [1] Rousseeuw P. J. and  Croux C. (1993).
  Alternatives to the Median Absolute Deviation.
  Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 88, No. 424, pp. 1273--1283.
- [2] J. K. Patel, C. H. Kapadia, and D. B. Owen, Dekker  (1976). 
  Handbook of statistical distributions.
- [3] Hampel (1974). The Influence Curve and Its Role in Robust Estimation. Journal of the American Statistical Association
  Vol. 69, No. 346 (Jun., 1974), pp. 383-393.
- [4] Vandervieren, E., Hubert, M. (2004) "An adjusted boxplot for skewed distributions". Computational Statistics & Data Analysis
  Volume 52, Issue 12, 15 August 2008, Pages 5186–5201.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd question the definition, classical or otherwise.  An "outlier" is a surprising point. Using any particular rule (even for symmetric distributions) is a flawed idea, especially nowadays when there are so many huge data sets. In a data set of (say) one million observations (not all that big, in some fields), there will be many many cases beyond the 1.5 IQR limit you cite, even if the distribution is perfectly normal.

Second, I'd suggest looking for outliers on the original data. It will nearly always be more intuitive. For instance, with income data, it is quite common to take logs. But even here I'd look for outliers on the original scale (dollars or euros or whatever) because we have a better feel for such numbers. (If you do take logs, I'd suggest log base 10, at least for outlier detection, because it is at least a little intuitive).

Third, when looking for outliers, beware of masking.

Finally, I am currently researching the "forward search" algorithm proposed by Atkinson and Riani for various sorts of data and problems. This looks very promising.

Comment: For a similar question you argued, using transformations for "substantive reason not statistical ones". I have been working on a dataset that has as many as 96 variables (a bankruptcy dataset) in which the task is (binary) classification. In that, all variables are in the range of 0 and 1 indicating that those must be proportional data. But, a few variables, though proportions, have values up till 10^10 digits. In order to contain those within 0 and 1, I divided the values by 10 ^ 10. I wonder whether I could use the transformed variables in the ML (classification) model or not?