# For univariate outlier analysis should I use z score if my data is skewed?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, outliers, z-score, univariate

1. If my data is skewed, does it mean that my data does not follow a normal distribution? How do we define various distributions?
2. What type of outlier analysis do I perform for the different type of distributions?

Comment: I am afraid this question is too broad. Have you checked multiple other questions tagged [tag:outliers] ?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129274/outlier-detection-on-skewed-distributions
https://www.cbs.nl/-/media/imported/documents/2010/15/2010-03-x10-pub.pdf