# Box and whiskers plot and outliers

Tags: outliers, boxplot

Why are data that are one and a half times the interquartile range (1.5IQR) or more, measured from the first and third quartiles, classed as outliers. Why 1.5?

Comment: This might help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73324/when-finding-outliers-from-the-interquartile-range-why-i-have-to-multiply-by-1-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most enlightening explanation but at lease there is someone to blame...

> Why one and a half times the width of the box? Why does that particular value demark the difference between "acceptable" and "unacceptable" values? Because, when John Tukey was inventing the box-and-whisker plot in 1977 to display these values, he picked 1.5×IQR as the demarkation line for outliers. This has worked well, so we've continued using that value ever since.
>   [source](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/boxwhisk3.htm)

and if you google for "1.5×iqr rule" there are more examples of why 1.5 actually works well, with wikihow beeing probably the best:

[How to Calculate Outliers](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Outliers)